# Binding to View's Width inside MvxLinearLayout

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I would like to create data binding to a `View`'s width that's located inside an `MvxLinearLayout` which is in an `MvxListView`.

So, `MvxListView` contains `MvxLinearLayout` items which contains `View`
items that need their `Width` to be bound to.

My layout code (removed unnecessary `ViewGroup` containers for clarity):

#### MvxListView

```
<Mvx.MvxLinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource ContainerItems; ItemClick DoSomething"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/container_item_template"
        />
```

#### container_item_template

```
<Mvx.MvxLinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource MyItems"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/my_item_template" />
```

#### my_item_template

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="20dp"
local:MvxBind="Width Width" />
```

I have created the following custom target binding:

```
public class ViewWidthCustomBinding : MvxAndroidTargetBinding
{
    public ViewWidthCustomBinding(object target) : base(target)
    {

    }

    public override Type TargetType
    {
        get { return typeof (double); }
    }

    protected override void SetValueImpl(object target, object value)
    {
        var realTarget = target as View;
        if (target == null)
            return;
        int width = 0;

        if (value is int)
        {
            width = (int) value;
        }
        else if (value is float)
        {
            width = (int) Math.Ceiling((float) value);
        }
        else if (value is double)
        {
            width = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)value);
        }

        if (width < 1)
        {
            return;
        }
        // my LayoutParameters here are always null for some reason
        // so the layout parameters are not set to the 40dp. 20dp, as it is set above in the item template
        // Looks like this gets applied first, and then it is replaced when actual parent (root) gets assigned since all my views get the 40do width, 20dp height assigned in the item template
        realTarget.LayoutParameters = new MvxLinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, MvxLinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent);

    }
}
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to handle the race condition **binding vs. layout inflation** (creating layout params from XML / Layout cycles).

I think you have to use a custom view like:

```
public class CustomView : View
{
    private double _customWidth;

    public double CustomWidth
    {
        get { return _customWidth; }
        set
        {
            _customWidth = value;
            var param = LayoutParameters;

            if (param != null)
            {
                param.Width = (int)_customWidth;
            }
            LayoutParameters = param;
        }
    }

    public override ViewGroup.LayoutParams LayoutParameters
    {
        get { return base.LayoutParameters; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                value.Width = (int)_customWidth;
                base.LayoutParameters = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public CustomView(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
    }

    public CustomView(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
    {
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
    {
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)
    {
    }
}
```

and then bind `CustomWidth` instead of `Width`.

```
<CustomView
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    local:MvxBind="CustomWidth MyWidth"/>
```

If you want to bind different types of width values (int, float, double) as in your binding target, you have to shift the conversion into a converter or just change your binding target a bit. I think you got the idea.

The good thing here is, that you don't have to know the type of the layout params (e.g. `MvxLinearLayout.LayoutParams`), because you don't have to create it on your own. This has 2 advantages:

- you don't override other properties, like margins, height, etc.
- it works in more than one parent layout

Comment: Great solution Sven. Thank you.